# Catching ClassCastException when you store an object in session and try to access it after a new deployment?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, classcastexception, runtimeexception

I'm facing a situation where if I stored a form in session, after making a new deployment of a war and trying to access the form, I get a java.lang.ClassCastException.

In order to make this transparent to the user, I wrote the following code:

```
try {
        command = (ReservationOfBooksCommand) request.getPortletSession().getAttribute(RESERVATION_OF_BOOKS_COMMAND_SESSION_NAME);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        request.getPortletSession().removeAttribute(RESERVATION_OF_BOOKS_COMMAND_SESSION_NAME);
    }
```

But not sure if there is a more elegant alternative as I don't like catching RuntimeExceptions and don't want to restart the server every time I deploy a new war.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the instanceof operator

```
Object command = request.getPortletSession().getAttribute(RESERVATION_OF_BOOKS_COMMAND_SESSION_NAME);

if(!(command instanceof ReservationOfBooksCommand)){
        request.getPortletSession().removeAttribute(RESERVATION_OF_BOOKS_COMMAND_SESSION_NAME);
}else{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the best solution but at least I see it more elegant than mine. Let's see if more alternatives come up :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this question with `tomcat`, I suggest that you:

1. Create a `META-INF/context.xml` in your own web application.
2. Add the following code line inside the context.xml.

Sample:

```
<context>
    <!-- stuff here-->

    <!-- Persistence Manager. This handles all of session Tomcat handles from our app. -->
    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="false">
        <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore" /> 
    </Manager>

</context>
```

As Michael Barker said, most application servers cleans requests and sessions after a redeployment, by default.

To allow Tomcat to store the session, set `saveOnRestart="true"`. This allows tomcat to store the session using `PersistentManager` in a `FileStore` (meaning, use a file storage system instead of a database storage system).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @The Elite Gentleman, the point i wanted to make is that I don't want a new restart everytime a redeploy, despite I could keep the session among restarts.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Blanco Martínez, Unfortunately, I'm not aware of redeploy without a restart as your objects needs to be registered in the app server classloader.

Comment: Ok, I'm using Liferay that has hot deployment feature for plugins (such as portlets, themes...), so my situation involves the redeployment of a plugin of portlets

Answer (score 0):

Some app servers allow the sessions to be cleared down before redeploying.  [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/resin/admin/deploy.xtp#web-app%20versioning) for example will continue to use the old code for the old session, moving new sessions onto new code.  Obviously you will need to expire the users session at some point.